# PowerShell switch statement not working in TCP/UDP port scanner

Tags: powershell, port-scanning

I am a PowerShell newbie trying to make a TCP and UDP port scanner. My code has a switch statement, where if you press 1 and enter that goes to the TCP function, 2 and enter the UDP function, or Q to quit it.

The issue is that the switch doesn't work properly. If you press 1 for TCP that just gives you the syntax prompt and asks you to press enter, then just ends the script - the same for TCP option 2. The Q button to quit works fine.

Can someone help? I can't spot what is wrong. My code is below

[image: Image of Code Output]

Thank you

```
Write-Host "Port Scanner"
function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'Options'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
    
    Write-Host "1: Press '1' for TCP."
    Write-Host "2: Press '2' for UDP."
    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
}
do
 {
     Show-Menu
     $selection = Read-Host "Make a selection"
     switch ($selection)
     {
         '1' {
                Write-Host "To scan for open ports, run the following command: scan-port [devicename] -ports"
                Function Scan-Port {
                    Param([string]$computername=$env:computername,
                          [array]$ports=@("21","22","23","25","80","443","3389")
                         )
                  #turn off error pipeline  
                  $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
  
                  #set values for Write-Progress
                  $activity="Port Scan"
                  $status="Scanning $computername"
                  $i=0
    
                       foreach ($port in $ports){ 
                       $i++
                        Write-Progress -Activity $activity -status $status `
                        -currentoperation "port $port" -percentcomplete (($i/$ports.count)*100)
       
                        #create empty custom object
                        $obj=New-Object PSObject
                        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -name "Computername" -value $computername.ToUpper()
                        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -name "Port" -value $port
        
                        $tcp=New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($computername, $port)
        
                        if ($tcp.client.connected) {
 
                            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -name "PortOpen" -value $True
            
                            [string]$rep=$tcp.client.RemoteEndPoint
                            [string]$ip=$rep.substring(0,$rep.indexof(":"))
 
                            }
                        else {
                #            Write-Warning "$computername not open on port: $port"
                            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType Noteproperty -name "PortOpen" -value $False
                         }  #end Else
         
                            write $obj 
                            $obj | Export-Csv -Append -path '.\PortScanResults.csv' -Delimiter ";" -Force
                            #disconnect the socket connection
                            $tcp.client.disconnect($False)
 
                        } #end foreach
        
                        #dispose and disconnect
                        $tcp.close()
 
                        Write-Progress -Activity $activity -status "Complete" -Completed
        
                } #end function
         } '2' {
              Function port-scan-udp {
              param($hosts,$ports)
              if (!$ports) {
                Write-Host "usage: test-port-udp <host|hosts> <port|ports>"
                Write-Host " e.g.: test-port-udp 192.168.1.2 445`n"
                return
              }
              $out = ".\scanresults.txt"
              foreach($p in [array]$ports) {
               foreach($h in [array]$hosts) {
                $x = (gc $out -EA SilentlyContinue | select-string "^$h,udp,$p,")
                if ($x) {
                  gc $out | select-string "^$h,udp,$p,"
                  continue
                }
                $msg = "$h,udp,$p,"
                $u = new-object system.net.sockets.udpclient
                $u.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 500
                $u.Connect($h,$p)
                # Send a single byte 0x01
                [void]$u.Send(1,1)
                $l = new-object system.net.ipendpoint([system.net.ipaddress]::Any,0)
                $r = "Filtered"
                try {
                  if ($u.Receive([ref]$l)) {
                    # We have received some UDP data from the remote host in return
                    $r = "Open"
                  }
                } catch {
                  if ($Error[0].ToString() -match "failed to respond") {
                    # We haven't received any UDP data from the remote host in return
                    # Let's see if we can ICMP ping the remote host
                    if ((Get-wmiobject win32_pingstatus -Filter "address = '$h' and Timeout=1000 and ResolveAddressNames=false").StatusCode -eq 0) {
                      # We can ping the remote host, so we can assume that ICMP is not
                      # filtered. And because we didn't receive ICMP port-unreachable before,
                      # we can assume that the remote UDP port is open
                      $r = "Open"
                    }
                  } elseif ($Error[0].ToString() -match "forcibly closed") {
                    # We have received ICMP port-unreachable, the UDP port is closed
                    $r = "Closed"
                  }
                }
                $u.Close()
                $msg += $r
                Write-Host "$msg"
                echo $msg >>$out
               }
              }
            }
                 }
     }
     pause
}
until ($selection -eq 'q')
```

Comment: Inside the `'1' { ... }` block you _define_ the `Scan-Port` function - but never _execute_ it. Add a `Scan-Port` statement on a separate line at the bottom of the block and it'll work

Comment: It's not about the switch - you are just printing that syntax prompt and then defining (and never calling) a function, so nothing else happens

Comment: As a side note, it is a good practice to define function outside the `switch` statement and maybe even outside the scope of the `Show-Menu` function.

Comment: Thank you all, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have another issue I am hoping you can help with. The TCP bit now works but the UDP scanner isn't accepting any paramaters. If I put in the syntax and then press Enter nothing happens. Thanks

```
         } '2' {
              Function portudp {
              Param($hosts,$ports)
              if (!$ports) {
                Write-Host "usage: portudp <host|hosts> <port|ports>"
                Write-Host " e.g.: portudp 192.168.1.2 445`n"
                return
              }
              $out = ".\scanresults.txt"
              foreach($p in [array]$ports) {
               foreach($h in [array]$hosts) {
                $x = (gc $out -EA SilentlyContinue | select-string "^$h,udp,$p,")
                if ($x) {
                  gc $out | select-string "^$h,udp,$p,"
                  continue
                }
                $msg = "$h,udp,$p,"
                $u = new-object system.net.sockets.udpclient
                $u.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 500
                $u.Connect($h,$p)
                # Send a single byte 0x01
                [void]$u.Send(1,1)
                $l = new-object system.net.ipendpoint([system.net.ipaddress]::Any,0)
                $r = "Filtered"
                try {
                  if ($u.Receive([ref]$l)) {
                    # We have received some UDP data from the remote host in return
                    $r = "Open"
                  }
                } catch {
                  if ($Error[0].ToString() -match "failed to respond") {
                    # We haven't received any UDP data from the remote host in return
                    # Let's see if we can ICMP ping the remote host
                    if ((Get-wmiobject win32_pingstatus -Filter "address = '$h' and Timeout=1000 and ResolveAddressNames=false").StatusCode -eq 0) {
                      # We can ping the remote host, so we can assume that ICMP is not
                      # filtered. And because we didn't receive ICMP port-unreachable before,
                      # we can assume that the remote UDP port is open
                      $r = "Open"
                    }
                  } elseif ($Error[0].ToString() -match "forcibly closed") {
                    # We have received ICMP port-unreachable, the UDP port is closed
                    $r = "Closed"
                  }
                }
                $u.Close()
                $msg += $r
                Write-Host "$msg"
                echo $msg >>$out
                $out | Export-Csv -Append -path '.\UDPPPortScanResults.csv' -Delimiter ";" -Force
     
               }
              }
            }
            portudp
                 }
     }
     pause

}
until ($selection -eq 'q')
```

[UDP Function Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9guaY.png)